# How to correctly connect my monitors?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

Please just help me get this straight. This is more of less how the computer rear looks.

[image]

I dont remember exactly how I had it before turning everything upside down in order to fix an issue I recently had, but right now I have a HDMI cable going to my main monitor whereas my second monitor is connected with a DVI cable to the second DVI slot (so the first DVI slot is empty now).

Is it correct to have it like this?

Before all this madness all I remember for sure is that my secondary monitor was connected to the FIRST DVI slot and that my first monitor was probably connected to the second one (I dont know why). However, I dont remember whether I had the HDMI cable connected too.

Comment: What is the problem you are having? You haven't told us anything about the PC, so how would we know if it is correct? Are the monitors not working the way you expect when connected?

Comment: About 2 days ago I was not able to get past the windows logo at the start up on Windows seven. Screen went black but the computer was still on. Seemed like the monitor was not getting any signal. I thought it was related to the graphic card so I opened up my computer and cleaned everything inside. When I reconnected everything it didnt work right away but it eventually did start up fine after 1 or 2 attempts. Thats why I need to know if its okay to connect monitors like this.

Comment: There are only a couple of combinations to try if your question is about connecting cables.  It isn't clear what you're asking.  Nobody here knows how you previously had things connected.

Comment: It helps to know the exact brand and type of video card you're using. Different cards use their outputs in different ways...

Answer (score 2):

I do not see any problem in the layout you propose.You can plug it in both DVI, first DVI & HDMI, second DVI & HDMI.

Then it is up to you to properly configure your display order in the display configuration of your OS.

Comment: But is it necessary to connect my first monitor to both HDMI and DVI? Or is it enough with only one of them?

Comment: You just need 1 connection per monitor.  So Monitor 1 -> HDMI, Monitor 2 -> DVI.  (or 1-DVI, 2-HDMI, doesn't really matter).  Once you get into Windows, you can go into your Graphics Settings and get the orientation set correctly for your actual physical layout.